# Virtualhosts - making available only certain websites without root folder

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have a DNS name as somename.dlinkddns.com

Also I've LAMP installed on my development machine.

I want to show my websites for client. 
It's possible to do it using virtual hosts.

e.g.  -  project1.somename.dlinkddns.com
         project2.somename.dlinkddns.com

And so on.

But if user changes address removing the first name before dot, he can see  all my projects on localhost.

I'd like to avoid  making available only some  sites.But not whole directory.

My version of Ubuntu is 12.10

Is it possible at all and how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A development box behind a dynamic IP address managed by D-Link dynamic DNS service. There are so many unprofessional variables at play here that 1) The question is not a good fit for ServerFault, and 2) Even if you manage to get it to work for you, it's a house of cards made of tissue paper just begging to be set on fire and kicked apart.

Comment: Do you mean that if someone enter `somename.dlinkddns.com` then directories such as `project1`,`project2`,`projectN` are listed ?

Comment: krisFR, yes,   exactly

Comment: Wesley,1) ok, I can  use  IP address. Does it change the situation?  2)Yes, it's house of cards but having this house of cards I'm free from copying dbs, scripts, and many other things during the development process. It'd save really a lot of time  later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a blank index.html file in your root directory.

Or edit your [.htaccess file](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/htaccess-directory-listing-enable-disable-allow-deny-prevent-htaccess-directory-listing/).

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be avoided using `Options -Indexes`

Locate the `<directory>` directive for `somename.dlinkddns.com` and add the option `-Indexes` :

```
<Directory /web>
   Options -Indexes
   ...
</Directory>
```

This option avoid directory listing.

The main feature here is `-`. By default Apache uses `+` which enable directory listing.